# awk to Join or merge lines on finding a pattern

Tags: awk, sed

I have some data in a file i need to sort (maybe using awk) and would appreciate some help if possible

Here is a small sample of the file..

```
DEFAULT,number,7996012132,,test,1,SP_A,SIX,,,

,,,,FOUR,,,

,,,,NINE,,,

,,,,TWO,,,

DEFAULT,number,7996020217,,test,1,SP_B,,,,,

DEFAULT,number,7996020218,,test,1,SP_B,,,,,

DEFAULT,number,7996020218,,test,1,SP_A,THREE,,,

,,,,TWO,,,

,,,,NINE,,,

,,,,THREE,,,

DEFAULT,number,7996020215,,test,1,SP_B,,,,,

DEFAULT,number,7996020216,,test,1,SP_A,SIX,,,

,,,,SEVEN,,,

,,,,EIGHT,,,

,,,,FOUR,,,
```

STEP 1 I would like bring lines together

```
DEFAULT,number,7996012132,,test,1,SP_A,SIX,,,,,,,FOUR,,,,,,,NINE,,,,,,,TWO,,,
DEFAULT,number,7996020217,,test,1,SP_B,,,,,
DEFAULT,number,7996020218,,test,1,SP_B,,,,,
DEFAULT,number,7996020218,,test,1,SP_A,THREE,,,,,,,TWO,,,,,,,NINE,,,,,,,THREE,,,
DEFAULT,number,7996020215,,test,1,SP_B,,,,,
DEFAULT,number,7996020216,,test,1,SP_A,SIX,,,,,,,SEVEN,,,,,,,EIGHT,,,,,,,FOUR,,,
```

STEP 2 i would like to filter out the lines with just the number FOUR present

```
DEFAULT,number,7996012132,,test,1,SP_A,,SIX,,,,,,,FOUR,,,,,,,NINE,,,,,,,TWO,,,
DEFAULT,number,7996020216,,test,1,SP_A,,SIX,,,,,,,SEVEN,,,,,,,EIGHT,,,,,,,FOUR,,,
```

STEP 3 i want to just display the following

```
7996012132 FOUR

7996020216 FOUR
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN {line=""} /DEFAULT/ {print line; line=$0} !/DEFAULT/ {line = line""$0} END {print line}' data.txt | awk -F, '/FOUR/ {print $3" FOUR"}'
```

An explanation:

```
# Initialize line variable to blank
BEGIN { line="" }            

# If the line contains DEFAULT, print what we have and start a new aggregation
/DEFAULT/ { print line; line=$0 }

# If the line does not contain DEFAULT, add this line to the variable
!/DEFAULT/ { line = line""$0 }

# At the end, print whatever we have
END { print line }
```

Then you can parse out the number you want based on lines that contain 'FOUR' with `,` as the field separator:

```
awk -F, '/FOUR/ {print $3" FOUR"}'
```

Comment: Fantastic Alex, thanks very much, really appreciated!! Have a great weekend!

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you!  If this solution helped you, could you mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

Part I:

```
/^$/ {next}                                     # this removes the empty records in your data
{
    printf "%s", (NR > 1 && /^DEF/ ?ORS:"") $1  # print
}
```

Test it:

```
$ awk -f foo.awk foo.txt
DEFAULT,number,7996012132,,test,1,SP_A,SIX,,,,,,,FOUR,,,,,,,NINE,,,,,,,TWO,,,
DEFAULT,number,7996020217,,test,1,SP_B,,,,,
DEFAULT,number,7996020218,,test,1,SP_B,,,,,
DEFAULT,number,7996020218,,test,1,SP_A,THREE,,,,,,,TWO,,,,,,,NINE,,,,,,,THREE,,,
DEFAULT,number,7996020215,,test,1,SP_B,,,,,
DEFAULT,number,7996020216,,test,1,SP_A,SIX,,,,,,,SEVEN,,,,,,,EIGHT,,,,,,,FOUR,,,
```

Part II:

```
/^$/ {next} 
/^DEF/ {
    if(NR>1&&foo~/FOUR/)print foo;foo=""
} 
{
    foo=foo $1
} 
END{if(foo~/FOUR/) print foo}
```