# Delimited file "|" with paragraph text including line breaks spanning multiple lines

Tags: awk, sed

I have a large TXT dataset that is delimited by `|` but there is a field that allows for paragraph text, which contains line breaks and blank lines. All lines that are not part of the paragraph text start with `AA|`. When I try to import into R via `readr` these values become NA because it doesn't follow the structure

Is there a way to use `sed` or `awk` to take a line if it doesn't start with `AA|` then to append it to the prior line that does with a space?

Input:

```
AA|5904060|9001084471200270|9000263372600200|Result Comment:
No (1, 3) Beta-D-Glucan detected.  

This assay does not detect certain fungi, including 
Cryptococcus species, which produce very low levels of (1, 
3) Beta-D-Glucan (BDG) and the Mucorales (e.g., Lichthemia, 
Mucor and Rhizopus), which are not known to produce BDG. 
Additionally, the yeast phase of Blastomyces dermatitidis 
produces little BDG and may not be detected by this assay.
|North Building|0|0
```

Goal Output:

```
AA|5904060|9001084471200270|9000263372600200|Result Comment: No (1, 3) Beta-D-Glucan detected.  This assay does not detect certain fungi, including Cryptococcus species, which produce very low levels of (1, 3) Beta-D-Glucan (BDG) and the Mucorales (e.g., Lichthemia, Mucor and Rhizopus), which are not known to produce BDG. Additionally, the yeast phase of Blastomyces dermatitidis produces little BDG and may not be detected by this assay.|North Building|0|0
```

Comment: please add a sample example of such lines and complete expected output for that sample to make it clearer as well as provide a test case to use for answers

Comment: there's also some Q&A that may help, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38957730/using-awk-to-join-lines-following-a-match and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39668670/awk-to-join-or-merge-lines-on-finding-a-pattern

Comment: great thank you I've added the sample and will check out that qa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `gawk` I would do something like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS="(\n|^)AA\\|"} NR>1 {print "AA|" gensub("\n"," ","g")}' myfile.txt
```

Explanation: Make the literal string `AA|`, only when found at the beginning of a line, the record separator. Assuming the very first line will begin with `AA|`, this will cause an empty record to be found first, and we discard it;  processing is done on records from 2 to end (NR > 1). In each record (delimited by this odd delimiter) replace every newline with a space, and print the record with `AA|` prepended to it (recall that the `AA|` that existed in the input file is the record separator, so it is no longer in the record itself).

The newline at the end of each record (right before `AA|` on the next line) is swallowed by the record separator, so you won't have errant spaces at the end of each output line - **except** for the last record, which is not terminated with "newline `AA|`" separator. The very last newline in the file survives and is converted to a space in the output; if this extra space at the end of the last record messes up your data, it must be fixed. (Not shown above.)

Comment: this worked perfectly, I had also determined that my files were produced on windows so the line endings were `\r\n` in addition so just changing this regex made it work perfectly.

Comment: @nahata5 - however, I made a mistake (which I will fix by editing the answer). I added a space between `AA|` and everything immediately following it, which you don't need. That was just careless on my part. The change is very small - just remove the comma from the `print` command.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
awk '
  /^AA\|/ { if (r) print r; r = $0; next }
  { r = r " " $0 }
  END { print r }
' input
```

If you want to avoid redundant spaces, you may add `gsub (/  /, " ", r)` in the code above, as follows:

```sh
awk '
  /^AA\|/ { if (r) print r; r = $0; next }
  { r = r " " $0; gsub (/  /, " ", r) }
  END { print r }
' input
```

Comment: so this actually just added a space to the lines that didn't start with `AA` at the beginning and did not append the line to the prior line that started with the `AA`. It definitely recognized the right lines, but I can't get it appended to the prior line

Comment: @nahata5: I don't understand your comment. When I apply my solution to the input you provided above, I get the result you ask. Something nasty must have happened.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT and assuming you know how many fields you should have in each record (8):

```
$ awk -v RS='([^|]*[|]){7}[^\n]*\n' '{$0=RT; $1=$1; gsub(/ *[|] */,"|")}1' file
AA|5904060|9001084471200270|9000263372600200|Result Comment: No (1, 3) Beta-D-Glucan detected. This assay does not detect certain fungi, including Cryptococcus species, which produce very low levels of (1, 3) Beta-D-Glucan (BDG) and the Mucorales (e.g., Lichthemia, Mucor and Rhizopus), which are not known to produce BDG. Additionally, the yeast phase of Blastomyces dermatitidis produces little BDG and may not be detected by this assay.|North Building|0|0
```

Otherwise if you don't have GNU awk or only know that all records start with a line starting with `AA|` then using any awk:

```
$ awk '/^AA\|/ { if (NR>1) prt(); rec="" } { rec = rec OFS $0 } END{ prt() }
    function prt(o){o=$0; $0=rec; $1=$1; gsub(/[[:space:]]*[|][[:space:]]*/,"|"); print; $0=o}
' file
AA|5904060|9001084471200270|9000263372600200|Result Comment: No (1, 3) Beta-D-Glucan detected. This assay does not detect certain fungi, including Cryptococcus species, which produce very low levels of (1, 3) Beta-D-Glucan (BDG) and the Mucorales (e.g., Lichthemia, Mucor and Rhizopus), which are not known to produce BDG. Additionally, the yeast phase of Blastomyces dermatitidis produces little BDG and may not be detected by this assay.|North Building|0|0
```